# What do the meanings of ponens and tollens have to do with Modus Ponens and Modus Tollens?

Tags: logic, terminology

There are two inference rules in propositional logic called Modus Ponens and Modus Tollens. I was wondering how the meanings of ponens and tollens have to do with the rules? That is, how does the Latin translation describe the rules themselves?

Comment: is this an etymology question?

Comment: yes. it is ....

Comment: i think it's the best subsite to ask on.

Comment: *Ponens* is Latin for *placing* and *tollens* is Latin for *removing*.  Modus ponens is commonly translated as *method of affirming*; Modus tollens is commonly translated as *method of denying*.  Placing/affirming, removing/denying.

Comment: @nwr thanks. are pono and tollo antonyms? I still don't see how their meanings are related to the two inference rules.

Comment: Yes, to the best of my understanding they are antonyms.

Comment: I've taken a shot at explaining, but I can't find anything on the etymology of the idiom.

Comment: They are actually short for "modus ponendo ponens" and "modus tollendo tollens". They may be translated in context as "the mode that by affirming, affirms" and "the mode that by denying, denies" respectively. There is also a modus ponendo tollens, which is exemplified by "not both A and B; A; therefore not B" and a modus tollendo ponens, which is exemplified by "A or B; not A; therefore B".

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

> Ponens is Latin for placing and tollens is Latin for removing. Modus ponens is commonly translated as method of affirming; Modus tollens is commonly translated as method of denying. Placing/affirming, removing/denying. – **nwr**

Obviously the two rules of inference are opposites, so one shouldn't be surprised their Latin titles are opposites. But it does raise the question, just what is one placing and removing? Some logician may have an appeal to history to clarify the origins of the terminology, perhaps from a passage of an ancient historian of Rome, however, it's quite possible that no such passage exists, and the construction of those neologisms all those years back is an open historical question.

I would presume it might reflect, however, the nature of the axiomatic method in argumentation. If we start with a premise P that helps us get to a conclusion Q by *modus ponens*, and we then show it is the case the P is indeed true, then we are allowed to **metaphorically place or put** Q into the next step of the argument since it is now known to be true. On the other hand, in *modus tollens*, we are showing that in our argument that we know the conclusion Q is invalid, then we are allowed to **metaphorically remove or take** the premise P from our argument structure since it can't possible be true given the truth of the consequent. Remember, an argument has to be both valid and sound, and exploring the truth conditions of the premises and conclusions give us an insight into whether the argument itself is valid. Good arguments come **taking out** all of the falisities and **putting in** as many truths as possible.

But, in the strictest sense, why specifically *ponens* and *tollens* were used for confirmation and disconfirmation (and are thus translated as such) and not some other Latin terms is a historical question.

Comment: For some reason, I remembered 'ponens' as meaning 'bridge', but college was a while ago.

Comment: @ScottRowe Likely a confabulation with 'pons' having a similar orthography to 'ponens'. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pons_asinorum

Comment: Yes, stupid brain stem! Oh, that's the other pons. Cervix means neck, so why... Nevermind.